# Find the total duration of mp3 in folder

Tags: python

I have made this code to get the duration of mp3 in a folder, and it works:

```
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

path = "D:/FILE/P. F. Ford - A Body on the Beach"


def convert(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    mins = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return(hours, mins, seconds)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            audio = MP3(os.path.join(root, file))
            # print(audio.info.length)
            hours, mins, seconds = convert(audio.info.length)
            print(str(int(hours)) + ":" +
                  str(int(mins)) + ":" + str(int(seconds)))
```

my question is how can i get the total duration of the files(the sum), instead of each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

path = "D:/FILE/P. F. Ford - A Body on the Beach"


def convert(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    mins = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return(hours, mins, seconds)

total_lenght = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            audio = MP3(os.path.join(root, file))
            # print(audio.info.length)
            hours, mins, seconds = convert(audio.info.length)
            print(str(int(hours)) + ":" +
                  str(int(mins)) + ":" + str(int(seconds)))
            total_lenght += audio.info.length

hours, mins, seconds = convert(total_lenght)
print("Total lenght of all audios:")
print(str(int(hours)) + ":" +
                  str(int(mins)) + ":" + str(int(seconds)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create variable, increase by `audio.info.length` for each filee, eventually `convert` and `print`, that is

```
total = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            audio = MP3(os.path.join(root, file))
            total += audio.info.length
hours, mins, seconds = convert(total)
print(str(int(hours)) + ":" + str(int(mins)) + ":" + str(int(seconds)))
```

Note that `x+=1` is more concise equivalent of `x = x+1`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer as more explanation.